# How can I enable java assertions in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc

I would like to use the Java `assert` keyword in my Spring web-app, primarily on my domain classes (checking invariants within constructors), but I cannot see how to enable runtime assertion checking.

For a normal java application, I would use the `-ea` switch with the java command, but I don't see how I can do that with Tomcat, etc.

Is this the recommended thing, or should I use the "Assert" class from the Spring framework? I'd rather keep my domain classes free of Spring dependencies, however.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For tomcat, add `-ea` to `JAVA_OPTS` (all java processes started), or even better to `CATALINA_OPTS` (only to web app engine).

Read the files `catalina.bat` or `catalina.sh` for more information on `JAVA_OPTS` and `CATALINA_OPTS`.

**Edited**: Thanks to comments from [@Joachim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer)

Comment: Thanks for that, but a) I'm using (for dev) VMware tc Server from within Eclipse (does that have `catalina.bat`?, b) I'd prefer to enable assertions just on my own web-app and c) how could I do that with something like VMWares CloudFoundry? Thanks again!

Comment: On a more serious note: `CATALINA_OPTS` would be the more appropriate point here. The difference is that `JAVA_OPTS` will be used on *all* invocations of Java from the Tomcat startup scripts (including the "connect to a running server and ask it to shut down" one), where `CATALINA_OPTS` will only be used for actually running the server. In this case the difference isn't too important, but for things like memory it's pretty important to use the right one (you don't want the tiny shutdown script to allocate 4 GB of memory).

Comment: @DecaniBass: well technically it should be possible to enable assertions on a per-webapp basis, since there's [`ClassLoader.setDefaultAssertionStatus()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#setDefaultAssertionStatus(boolean)) but unfortunately I don't know *if* and *how* those applications servers are exposing that option.

Comment: You could also use DEBUG_OPTS which would allow you to have this only enabled dev/qa environments.