# NullPointerException after assert in java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, assert

The following method is a setter for a field called election_date which is of type java.util.date. It is part of a tomcat application.

Upon execution, I get a Null pointer exception on the line:

```
    System.out.println("ELECTION DATE: " + this.election_date.toString());
```

---

```
public void setElection_date(Date election_date) {

    this.election_date = election_date;
    assert (this.election_date != null);
    assert (this.election_date.toString()) != null;
    System.out.println("ELECTION DATE: " + this.election_date.toString());
}
```

---

EDIT: Please don't tell me it's being garbage collected. I may be slightly off the Balmer Peak, but not that far off.

Comment: did you set the -ea option when running the program?

Comment: No. What does the -ea option do?

Comment: Yes, spot on. Assertions were disabled. Now I realize how I wasted 3 hours assuming the assertion was true. I will accept both your answers as soon as I am able. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In eclipse go on Run Configurations, arguments and set `-ea` into VM arguments

`-ea` options mean enable assertions, without it the assertions are ignored

Answer (score 5):

Assertions are disabled by default. Your variable `election_date` is `null`.

Add `-ea` to `JAVA_OPTS` before run Tomcat.

[Programming With Assertions: Enabling and Disabling Assertions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html#enable-disable)

> > **By default, assertions are disabled at runtime.** Two command-line switches allow you to selectively enable or disable assertions.
> >
> > To enable assertions at various granularities, use the **-enableassertions**, or **-ea**, switch.  To disable assertions at various granularities, use the -disableassertions, or -da, switch.

Also look at question: [How can I enable java assertions in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120669/how-can-i-enable-java-assertions-in-tomcat)